# Getting methods without declaring new instances

Tags: java

What is the idea on how to get the methods from an already declared instance that is declared on another class?

Grow Class

```
public class Grow {

public static void main( String [] args ) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final GrowPanel growPanel = new GrowPanel();
    ButtonPanel btnPanel = new ButtonPanel();
    frame.add( growPanel );
    frame.add( btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize( 400, 300 );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
```

}

ButtonPanel Class

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JButton btn;

public ButtonPanel() {
    btn = new JButton("Pause");
    add(btn);
    btn.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if( e.getActionCommand().equals("Pause")){
        System.out.println("RESUME");
        //growPanel.pause();
        btn.setText("Resume");
    } else {
        System.out.println("PAUSE");
       // growPanel.start();
        btn.setText("Pause");
    }
}
```

}

GrowPanel Class

```
class GrowPanel extends JComponent {
private int x;
private int y;
private Timer timer;
ButtonPanel b;

public GrowPanel() {
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    startPaiting();
}

public void startPaiting() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
                changeState();
                repaint();      
        }
    },0,  100 );
}

public void pause(){
    timer.cancel();
    startPaiting();
}

 public void start(){
    timer.cancel();
    x = 10;
    y = 10;
    startPaiting();
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    g.fillOval( x, y, 10, 10 );
}
private void changeState(){
    x+=10;
    if( x >= 400 ) {
        y+=10;
        x = 0;
    }
    if( y >= 300 ){
        y = 10;
    }
}
```

}

I already declared a new instance of GrowPanel in Grow. I just don't know how to get the methods of GrowPanel from ButtonPanel without declaring a new instance of GrowPanel inside ButtonPanel. Is the idea even possible? So far I've been given some topics that might help: Setters / getters, Singleton Pattern...but so far the idea has been elusive.

Comment: Did you try the reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a new instance of GrowPanel in your button panel. You want to use the same instance as the one the main frame uses. So, just pass it to the button panel:

```
ButtonPanel btnPanel = new ButtonPanel(growPanel);

...

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JButton btn;
    private GrowPanel growPanel;

    public ButtonPanel(GrowPanel growPanel) {
        this.growPanel = growPanel;
    }
    ...
}
```